# VBA to Group Pivot Table Date Columns to have > and < Groupings on the Extremes

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, grouping

I'm new to VBA and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have a macro already to create a pivot table that has month columns, however those month columns are dependent on the input data. I would like to use VBA to code such that the pivot table columns are: **< Month N-1**, Month N-1, Month N (determined by a cell value on another sheet),....., **> Month N + 11**. These are my current thoughts, although this doesn't seem to make it group at all.
`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Months").Group Start:=Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth((Range("Macro!H8"), -1) + 1, End:=Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth((Range("Macro!H8"), 11)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for anyone interested, I went a different direction than my initial thoughts:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Years")
    .LabelRange.Cells(1, 2).Group Start:=(Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("Macro!G24"), -2) + 1), End:=Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("Macro!G24"), 11), Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, True)
                  .Position = 1
End With
```